# На старый ноутбук, лучше Windows 10 или Windows 11?

Tags: windows, ноутбук

Конфигурация ноутбука:

| Компоненты | - |
| --- | --- |
| Процессор | Intel core i5-2410m |
| Озу | 4 гб DDR3 |
| Видео карта | Внутренняя: Nvidia GeForce Gt 550m(2GB) |
| - | Интегрированая Intel HD Graphics 3000 |
| TPM | Нету |
| Secure Boot | Нету |
| Жесткий диск | SSD 256 GB (PATRIOT BURST) |

Что выбрать?
Ноут для Работы, Интернет-серфинга, и Гта 5

Comment: Мало оперативы, я бы w7 ставил вообще на него

Comment: Не соответствует минимальным системным требованиям Windows 11

Comment: Будучи постоянным пользователем Windows, на такое железо мб посоветовал бы даже что-нибудь линуксовое поставить, если нет потребности в каком-то специфичном софте, потому что Win 7 все-таки уже просрочилась, а с 10 очень тяжело будет.

Comment: Если ноутбук не слишком сложно разбирается и в нём одна плашка 4гб памяти, стоит по возможности ещё одну плашку докупить и поставить (а ещё лучше две плашки по 8гб)

Comment: Для каких целей ноут ? Может Fedora зайдет, если для разработки чисто.

Comment: Нормальный ноут. Памяти добавить хотя бы до 8 гигов, да поставить линукс с XFCE/LXDE - и поработает ещё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

официальная винда не встанет, tpm нет, какую то сборку если только, десятка ощутимо легче, у меня примерно такой конфиг на буке, стояла 11, стояла десятка, сейчас все это снес ввиду неиспользования, оставил линух, по факту десятка полегче, 11 подтупливала даже без анимации, на 11 почему то постоянные проблемы были с wifi картой, так что надо бы для начала узнать как дрова железа работают на новой винде, я бы десятку поставил или линух, семерку уже толку ставить нет, обнов софта все меньше

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Установил windows 10 pro, все быстро и хорошо работает!